# Process terminating after exiting the remote shell in erlang

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

I started a process and registered it using `register(?MODULE,PID)` from remote shell. Now when i am exiting the remote shell the process is getting terminated.

After a new remote connection If i check it from `whereis(?MODULE)` it says undefined.

Comment: What is your exact question? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: What do you mean by remote shell? How do you connect to the node remotely?

Comment: How have you spwan the process? May be you've used `spawn_link` somewhere and got linked to the shell?

Comment: @Amiramix I used 

 /srv/myapp/erts-7.2/bin/erl -sname rocky1 -setcookie myapp -remsh 'myapp@ip-10-0-43-43' -boot start_clean

Comment: @Lol4t0 I tried it starting it with spawn(fun() -> end). as well as starting it manually i.e. Without spawn. None of them worked. As soon as I disconnected from the remote shell. It disconnected.

Comment: @A.Sarid I am starting a process on one master server which will periodically check all the slaves. For testing purposes I tried starting it manually. But it didn't work through remote shell. So, I had to create a separate application which I linked to the supervision tree and that application works fine. 

I am curious to know why a process spawned through remote shell terminated. Even when it was registered.

Comment: Then provide your code. Because _usually_ that works